# Unable to create a column in a dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column in an existing dataframe by matching values with the other dataframe.

## Dataframe 1 - (movies)

```
index  |  rating  | movie_id  |  movie_title
--------------------------------------------
0      |    5     |    100    |  Inception
1      |    4     |    101    |  Starwars
```

## Dataframe 2 - (recommendations)

```
index  |  rating   | movie_id  
------------------------------
0      |    3.9    |    101    
1      |    4.7    |    100
```

## What I would like to have - (recommendations):

```
index  |  rating    | movie_id  |  movie_title
--------------------------------------------
0      |    3.9     |    101    |  Starwars
1      |    4.7     |    100    |  Inception
```

## What I tried to do : (It doesn't make sense though)

```
pd.merge(movies , recommendations, on ='movie_id', how ='left')
```

> This doesn't make sense because both dataframes are not of same sizes. Recommendation dataframe's size is given by user through console.

Comment: Both dataframes don't have to be the same size for `pd.merge()`. Please show what happens when you try the merge. Do you get an error, or an incorrect result?

Comment: @Craig - I'm getting this error `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: Please edit your post and place the complete error, and the code you are using, into the post with proper formatting.

Comment: The error is telling you that the `movie_id` column is of different types in the two dataframes. In one dataframe it is integers and in the other dataframe it is objects (maybe string?). Update your question with the output of `print(movies.info())` and `print(recommendations.info())` and that will help someone figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary of one matching row in `df1` as key and the values to be transferred as dictionary value

```
d=dict(zip(df1.movie_id,df1.movie_title))
```

Use `df.map()` method to map values in the dictionary to `df2`

```
df2['movie_title']=df2['movie_id'].map(d)



 index  rating  movie_id movie_title
0      0     3.9       101    Starwars
1      1     4.7       100   Inception
```

Comment: I'm getting `NaN` values

Comment: That should work. Ensure the column names are right. It working for me. Yes if there are some movie_ids that are not in both dataframes their movie_title in df2 will be null. And that is correct because there is nothing being mapped.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
newdf=pd.merge(recommendations,movies[movies.columns[1:]], how='left',on='movie_id')
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
   rating  movie_id movie_title
0     3.9       101    Starwars
1     4.7       100   Inception
```